# Converting Javascript Date getTime()

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, date

I have a problem,which I can't find a solution.I have a MVC Project,where I work only in locale date ( Bulgarian Time GMT +2 ).I transfer my date in seconds and then in my javascript code I translate it in the seconds.Then I  want to translate it again but I get 3 hours less.

```
var date = new Date(1970,0,1);  
date.setSeconds(1476086900); //    10.10.2016 8:20 a.m
```

Then when i transfer it with getTime(function) and divide it to 1000 to get seconds again I get aproximetly 10k seconds less - > 5 a.m.

```
var apprSeconds =  date.getTime() / 1000 ;
```

apprSeconds is 1476076100.

The problem is that I get different values:

1476086900
1476076100

Thank you for your help.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to accomplish? It is a bit unusual to say "1 January 1970 at 00:00:1476086900".  The behavior you are seeing is exactly as described by JavaScript: `setSeconds` assumes the local time zone and `getTime` is UTC. Are you asking _why_ JavaScript is this way or is there a specific problem we can help you with?

Comment: Your `date.setSeconds(1476086900);` line of code returns the number of miliseconds between 1/1/1970 and the new date (`1476049100000`) which is exactly what `date.getTime()` returns

Comment: @RayToal I want a solution and how to get the local time seconds after getTime()?

Comment: Since `getTime` gives you seconds since the epoch (and is inherently UTC), can you not just add the time zone offset?

Comment: Because when i use getTimeoffset() - it returns 120 mins but actually i need 180 mins,because the difference is that.

Answer (score 0):

The code isn't doing what you think. When you do:

```
var date = new Date(1970,0,1);  
date.setSeconds(1476086900);
```

A Date is created for 1 Jan 1970 in the host system's local time zone, which is UTC+02:00. Adding seconds sets the **local** seconds, so you're still UTC+02:00.

However, the internal time value is UTC, so When you do:

```
date.getTime() / 1000
```

you get the UTC seconds. Since you're treating the initial value as local, you need to allow for the timezone offset:

```
date.getTime() / 1000 - date.getTimezoneOffset() * 60;
```

which should give you the original value in seconds. Note that the timezone offset is expressed in minutes and is -ve for timezones east of Greenwich and +ve for timezones west (i.e. opposite to the typical sense).

```js
var seconds = 1476086900;
var date = new Date(1970,0,1);
date.setSeconds(seconds);

// Date in host timezone
console.log('date:  ' + date.toString());

// Date UTC time value
console.log('UTC time value in seconds: ' + date/1000)

// returns original seconds value
console.log('Time value in seconds adjusted for host timezone: ' +
             (date / 1000 - date.getTimezoneOffset() * 60));
```

Which shows that the difference between the two time values is the timezone offset.

#### PS

The term "local" here means based on the host timezone settings, which might be set based on locale (i.e. geographical location) or some other policy (such as whatever the user or administrator has set it to).